# How to delete a step, or a frame from abaqus odb using python or cpp scripting

Tags: python, c++, abaqus

How to delete a step, or a frame from abaqus odb using python or cpp scripting?
I need to update data in an odb file, without creating a new one.
I want to be able to delete a step or a frame and rewrite the data.

Comment: are you wanting a script to do this in cae / abaqus viewer? or a script that will operate directly on to the results database?

Comment: maybe you can do it from the command line with `abaqus odbcombine` (see manual section 3.2.19 ).

Comment: @churchwalk I want to write a script to directly change the odb. I know a lot about cpp and python scripts for Abaqus, I just cant find a command to delete a step from and Odb

Comment: you can not delete anything from an odb. You need to persue making a copy and retaining what you want to keep.